# Cannot assign "'type1'": "users.user_type" must be a "types" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a 'users' model that have a OneToOneField to UserModel and a ForeignKey Field to 'types' model. How can I save the ForeignKeyField in database?

models.py:

```
class types(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(types, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mobile + "(" + self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name + ")"

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_users(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        users.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.users.save()
```

views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.users.mobile = form.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
            user.users.user_type = form.cleaned_data.get('user_type')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = forms.SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'user/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
lass SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_type = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'password1',
                  'password2',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'mobile',
                  'user_type',
                  )
```

But, I have this error:

> Cannot assign "'type1'": "users.user_type" must be a "types" instance.

Comment: Exactly to what should `user` in `types` refer?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem each user have a type ... and it stores in types table ... user refer id in types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form.cleaned_data.get('user_type')
```

You will get a string from the code.
But users.user_type should be set as an instance of types.
So, you should create an instance using an existed user before calling form.save().

```
types.objects.create(user=user1, name=form.cleaned_data.get('user_type'))
```

By the way, why types have to have a OneToOneField to User?

Comment: thanks ... it's work! ... i removed the user field in types ... and add these line in views.py ... ```models.types.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data.get('user_type'))``` ```users.user_type_id = models.types.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data.get('user_type'))```